# Adding y-axis on right side to Ridge Plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, ridgeline-plot

I would like to add a sample y-axis tick on the right side of the Ridge plot, to know what is the range of values of all the plots. Preferably I would like to add it only to one of the subplots and not to all of them.

My plot is based on the seaborn 'ridge plot' example at: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/kde_ridgeplot.html

I've tried the following code with no luck:

```
g.set(yticks=[0,200])
g.set_y_label_position("right")
g.set_ylabels('[Range]',fontsize=9,fontweight="normal")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify one particular axes from a FacetGrid, you can get a reference from the list `g.axes`

Here is how I would go about it

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create the data
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)


g.map(label, "x")

#
# Changes from seaborn example below this point
#

# Set the subplots to overlap
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.25, right=0.9)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
#g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True, right=False, top=True, offset=5)

for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    if ax.is_first_row():  # can use .is_last_row() to show spine on the bottom plot instead
        ax.yaxis.tick_right()
        ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
        ax.set_ylabel("MW")
    else:
        ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        [l.set_visible(False) for l in ax.get_yticklabels()]  # necessary because y-axes are shared
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. How would I add the yaxislabel on that side? I tried this inside the `if` statement:

    `ax.yaxis.set_label_text('MW')`

But the label was positioned on the left side.

Comment: use `ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")`. I've amended my answer